# SLES crash dump

Tags: suse, sles

I would like to test whether my server creating a crash dump upon a OS crash. I can see the `/etc/sysconfig/kdump` config file is configured.

So I issued the command to kernel panic `echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger` so it crashed the server but it never create a dump file for some reason. This is HP BL460g7 blade with ASR disabled.

When I trigger the kernel panic it crashed but stays about 10 minutes (looks like its trying to save a crash dump) but it never. I checked the message logs but cannot see reason why its not dumping. Main problem is how do I find why it's not dumping a crash file, is there are any logs I can check what has really gone wrong?

I'm using SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64) SP 1.

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the steps explained here?

[SUSE Support - Configure kernel core dump capture](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=3374462)

The most important tasks should be:

- install kdump, kexec-tools and makedumpfile
- add crashkernel=... to the kernel command line (Grub)
- chkconfig boot.kdump on
- ensure that you have enough free space in /var/crash (default dir)

Then please reboot your system and run:

```
sync; echo c >/proc/sysrq-trigger
```

After another boot please check for new files in `/var/crash`. If this doesn't work for you, please show us the content of `/etc/sysconfig/kdump` and at least the output of

```
cat /proc/cmdline
chkconfig boot.kdump
```

Do you have a display connected to the machine?